# Difference between two averages in excel power pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have the following data table in excel, showing how many apples i collected in the first 12 hours of the day, and how many oranges i collected in the last 12 hours of the day, for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd of January 2018:

[image: Apples and Oranges data]

I want to know how many apples and oranges i collected on average per day, and therefore make the following pivot table:

[image: Apples and Oranges pivot]

I then want to clearly see how many more oranges i collected than apples, per day. I therefore make a Calculated Field to calculate the difference between the columns "Average of Apples" and "Average of Oranges". I try the 2 following solutions as formulas in my Calculated Field:

1. Delta averages = Apples-Oranges
2. Delta averages 2 = AVERAGE(Apples )-AVERAGE(Oranges )

However, neither formula returns the differences in averages that I wished for. Instead, I obtain the difference in sums of all apples of all oranges, which isn't of interest to me:

[image: Apples and Oranges calculated fields attempts]

Does anyone know why the above doesn't work? Is there a way of calculating such a difference of averages in Pivot?

To be clear, the result I am looking for is:

```
01/01/2018 0.5
02/01/2018 2.5
03/01/2018 2.5
```

I know there are other easier ways of doing this than pivot, but I want to do it in power pivot to have this easily updatable with more data.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's dangerous to work with averages because there are lots of ways to get in trouble.  You can't combine averages in the same way you combine their source values.  In your example, you aren't really even working with the numbers you describe.

You've divided each day into four 6 hour periods.  You collect apples during two periods and oranges during a different two.  If you want to compare days, the periods are artificial divisions.  On Jan 1, you collected 4 apples and 5 oranges; Jan 2, 4 apples and 9 oranges; Jan 3, 5 apples and 10 oranges.  At the day level, there aren't averages, just totals.

The averages you're calculating in the first pivot table are a strange, artificial number; they're not even average per period.  They're the average per period for the selected periods during which that fruit was being collected.  To get average per day, you would need to average the day totals across all days to produce one grand average for each fruit, which isn't useful for your purpose.

If you want to compare fruits and days, use the day totals for each fruit.  Then you can use simple subtraction to make comparisons.  You can do that in the pivot table by just picking Sum as the aggregation rather than Average.  All of your results will then make sense.

That said, if you're just interested in the mechanics of working with "average per relevant collection period by fruit by day" in your pivot table, we can do that.  You don't show what formulas you're using in the pivot table, but I can guess from what is shown.

It looks like your first "average of delta averages" column is doing the subtraction on the actual counts and then aggregating by day.  Your second delta column is producing the same result.  That's because your pivot table is averaging each individual number (average of a single number is the same number), and then doing the subtractions and aggregating by day.

The pivot table does its work at the data level, then aggregates, when you define your own math for the values.  You can't get to the result you're looking for by doing this in one step inside the pivot table.  You're looking for successive calculations, building on the results of the first pivot table.  The simplest way to do that is to create your first pivot table as shown in your example.  That gets all of your data rolled up, which you wanted to accomplish to make it updatable.  Then do your subtractions on those results outside the pivot table in an adjacent column.